# The difference between a virtual door-lock and a public key

Tags: cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, secret-sharing, binary-code

The thing that helped me to understand what is a "public key" was to parallel it with a door lock:
The door lock is *public* in the sense that anyone can try to unlock it and the door key is the *private* in the sense that generally, only certain user or people should use it.

---

**Virtualwise**, what is the essential difference between say the most advanced (3D-virtual-reality) *door-lock* to the simplest (virtual) *public key*?

Is the difference primarily in quantity (the amount of information to try to brute force) or is it primarily in quality (the types of problems to try to solve)?

Comment: What is a "virtual-reality-door-lock"?

Comment: Hello @schroeder , I meant to a virtual reality environment in which we have modeled a house with a grade A door lock on the front door.

Comment: So ... you want to know the difference between 2 fictional items you made up?

Comment: I think the various examples in the linked question will help. Especially: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24407/principle-of-asymmetric-algorithm-in-plain-english/26210#26210

Comment: @schroeder I misunderstand your comment because you well know that public keys are not fictional and modeling reality is something serious so I would assume that the questions is **principally** valid.

Comment: Modelling requires an epistemologically stable common foundation between items. You are making up all your items. So, either only *you* know the commonalities, or you are hoping we will come up with a cohesive model for you. So, set aside your proposed model, and investigate the models provided by the linked question. Modelling reality is principally valid. That's what the other question does.

Comment: @schroeder indeed I didn't have any specific idea and hoped for someone to answer with examples of actual usecases and I don't investigate this so please never mind, but I did try to ask a new better question :https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/259438/is-the-term-only-unlocking-key-more-accurate-than-the-term-private-key